# How to use ANTLR4 to get a list of functions and classes in string format regardless of the programming language?

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

Say we have some files "index.js", "main.java", "test.rs", and I want to output a list of functions/classes (along with doc comments) in these files.

For example:

```
output: [
"function jsFunction() {
   console.log("hello world!");
}",

"class HelloWorld": [
"// This function prints "Hello World"
public void javaFunction() {
    this.print();
}", 
"// This is a private method for printing
private void print() {
   System.out.println("Hello world");
}
"
],

"// This is a rust function
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
"
]
```

Is it possible to do this with ANTLR4 and Python? Assuming I have all parsers and lexers for popular languages.

Comment: This is easy with Antlr, [grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4), [Trash](https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.Trash) and XPath expressions, but it is not in Python. You can do it with Antlr Visitors in Python, but it is laborious.

Comment: @kaby76 Would you mind elaborate this as a formal answer? I've been trying with grammars-v4 in Python. But it doesn't really work well. I'm open with writing this thing in Java. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So your question really is something like this:

> Given a string containing arbitrary code, how to use ANTLR to determine what the programming language is?

right? And you have grammars/parsers for a large amount of languages.

The naive way would be to parse the code with every parser and stop whenever one does not produce an error. There are at least 3 problems with this:

1. it will be rather slow;
2. you will always need a "full code snippet". For example, the code `System.our.println("...");` is a valid Java statement, but the generated Java parser will not recognize it as a valid "compilation unit";
3. some code could be (successfully) parsed by multiple parsers.

Comment: To recognize the language, I would simply just look at the file extension. The goal is to extract all functions and classes from a set of input files, and convert them to strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on Java, the rest would be similar.

1. Starting with grammar [Java Grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java) implement a visitor for the rules you are interested in. For example, for Java grammar you will need to implement visitor methods:

`visit_classDeclaration`,`visit_methodDeclaration`.

2. Inside the visitor methods you have the name of the class method and access to the first and the last token corresponding to the rule. Using the token range, you can restore the source code from the token stream, including formatting.
3. If you want to preserve comments, you will need tokens from the hidden channel.

An alternative approach for 2 and 3 would be to get the line/column location for the first and the last tokens and the source code from the original file.